# Are all distributions with conjugate priors exponential families?

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, bayesian

The Wikipedia page for [conjugate priors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_prior) lists [several examples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_prior#Table_of_conjugate_distributions). Of the ones I'm immediately familiar with, all are exponential families. This leads me to wonder whether all families distributions that admit conjugate priors are exponential families.

More explicitly: suppose that $D$ is a family of distributions over $X$, parameterised by $\Theta$, that is, a probability measure $p(x;\theta)$ for each $\theta\in\Theta$. Suppose $D$ admits a conjugate prior. Does it follow that the family $D$ is an exponential family? If not, what is a simple counterexample, i.e. a family of distributions that admits a conjugate prior but is not an exponential family?

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/192554/119261

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> what is a simple counterexample, i.e. a family of distributions that admits a conjugate prior but is not an exponential family?

Uniform model with Pareto prior

Comment: For the benefit of readers, since this wasn't completely straightforward to google: "uniform model" refers to a family of distributions on the reals, with a single parameter $a>0$, defined by probability density function $\rho(x;a) = 1/a$ if $0\le x\le a$, and 0 otherwise. It's not an exponential family because the distributions don't all have the same support, and it has a conjugate prior given by the Pareto distribution. Details are given in [these notes](https://tminka.github.io/papers/minka-uniform.pdf), for example.